# How to reproduce this fold effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, path, illustration, branding

I love the LATAM Airlines logo and I'd like to learn how to make that "fold" we can see on the edges I marked with those green circles, connecting one line to another:

[image]

That could be something "easy" for those who are "nasa-level" on Illustrator, and because of that, you may tell me a good way (maybe the "right" way) to do it. I mostly created type-based logos, but I'm trying to develop myself in creating symbol-based logos. I'm not so good with Illustrator, but that's why I'm here again asking your help so I can improve my skills learning with who are already good at it.

Just a note: once upon a time someone here on Graphic Design stackexchange who highly criticized me for making a question about something I had no idea how to do it, so I'd just ask a favor: if you are not willing to help, don't reply. We're here to help each other and, also, to learn. I've been using StackExchange during my whole professional life, and unfortunately sometimes there are people with no education, you know that.

I appreciate!

Comment: Welcome (back?) to **GD.SE** - please take a look around [tour] to get a sense of this community, our values and purpose, and look over [ask] and [answer] in order to learn what makes a good question here, and how to frame it to get the best results. I know it will help defuse potential comments if you can share what you've tried so far!

Answer (score 5):

Draw overlapping shapes with the pen. As well you can start from rotated rectangles and make only edits.

[image]

Hidden parts can be whatever, but visible corners probably need some tinkering Here's a zoomed detail:

[image]

You must be familiar with the anchor editing tools except in case you get it right at the first attempt. Having smart quides and snap to points ON helps. Be sure other snaps and pixel alignment are OFF.

**Not asked:** I would draw the folding a little differently. The white shape should have vertical right edge, if it's intended to be a folded planar stripe. Should it be planar? Artist's opinion decides. Here it is without a fill.

[image]

This is from Inkscape. There node editing somehow seems easier than in Illustrator (=an opinion again). One tool fits to all node edits, there's no need to switch like in Illustrator.

**ADD due the comment**

[image]

**Rounding one corner:** A highly skilled pen user can draw perfect curves straight in the fly, no edits are needed. The rest of us must do them more or less.

In inkscape rectangles, ellipses and other preset shapes must be converted to paths for node editing (Path > Object to Path)

Then add 2 new nodes around the corner (=double click with node tool), delete the original corner node (=Del), drag the handles. If a handle happens to be in a node, it can be dragged out if you hold Shift at the same time.

**More tutorials:** You must do web searches by yourself and see Inkscape's own website. On-demand tutorials are downvote magnets in this site, because many of us expect higher level content than repeated user guides.

Comment: Many many thanks! Your first picture figures it out at all! I don't know if it's just me, but I have so much difficulty to see the logic in the arts behind logos, I mean, you said that those elements are overlapping and I just couldn't figure it out since it's something relatively simple. I'd like to ask if you are able to see those logics because you already made something similar or if someone taught those things to you. I'm a web designer but I really wanna be good at logo design, which is for me the first and most important step of the whole thing behind a brand.

Comment: @joaogdesigner I have learned this by accident. In the first hour I had a drawing program, which allowed layered shapes I drew a couple of shapes and they happened to overlap. It resembled a folding. Generally I like to find out how things are done. It's pure curiosity.

Comment: Whether is curiosity or not, it works! I've read about Inkscape on an article but I'd never even heard about it. Is it worth? I use Illustrator (old Corel's user) because it's in the CC subscription. Is it paid?

Comment: @joaogdesigner Inkscape is freeware. Voluntary enthusiasts develop it. $0,- price shouldn't be an obstacle. A portable version (=no installation, copy only the files) doesn't mess your machine. It's strong in different areas than Illustrator. Illustrator handles coherently with other Adobe's stuff general color management, CMYK printing and contains many other things that Inkscape users still only dream (blends, path gradients, 3D, direct copy and paste to Photoshop, stroke trace, Shape Builder, etc). I use Inkscape when I know I must draw with the pen and edit curves

Comment: I will take a look. To make those rounded corners, do I have to add new anchor points?

Comment: I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I appreciate! Also, if you find related articles to this subject on the internet, please paste here the links so I can have other references to work on. Tks!

Comment: @joaogdesigner learning to draw is to learn to see whats inside and behind things Anyway theres a easier way to see this. Draw a zigzag. Offset a bopy join the cvertical tangents fill with shapebuilder. Which is WAY easier thatn this thing